# .net core 3.1 Angular boilerplate authorization fails in IIS

Tags: angular, iis, .net-core, identityserver4

I have a problem when publishing app to IIS.
Seems the authentication part of the Asp net core template needs something to handle requests that don’t come from localhost:

I host the app on `localhost/app`, but the angular authorization.service makes requests to `localhost/_configuration`, 
instead of to `localhost/app/_configuration`.
I think the reason for that is that the Asp.net boilerplate uses *fetch* to get the data:

```
const response = await fetch(ApplicationPaths.ApiAuthorizationClientConfigurationUrl);
```

The best thing is, if I change the command to:

```
const response = await this.httpClient.get<Response>(ApplicationPaths.ApiAuthorizationClientConfigurationUrl).toPromise();
```

then I get the endless loop.

If I add the `app/` to the start of the links in api-authorization.constants.ts, then the request gets to the right address, hovewer, after

> `authorize?clientid=....`

call now comes

> `error?errorid=....`

call, and then my angular app tries to route to `app/home/error` which fails.

I do not see what is wrong in my configuration, it is pretty much default one.
In IIS Express it runs without problems.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a deployUrl parameter inside your angular-cli.json. Have you configure that to /app when publish angular?

Comment: did you set the base href when you build the build the site? and you could use the URL rewrite rule to set the angular routs like: `<rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/MyApp/" />
        <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />-->
      </rule>`

Comment: Just tried using deployUrl. That just changes the <script src=""> src attributes. The url that is targeted is still localhost/_configuration.

Comment: jeah, base href is set to /app/. But the problem is not just in the url(s), something also needs to be done to make sure the auth flow doesn't error.

Comment: could you share your authorization code?

Comment: just create new .net core 3.1 app with individual accounts. Without changing any code you can get it. I also opened an issue at: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19852

Answer (score 0):

there were two bugs in asp net core repository.
The first bug was because of the authorization links that began with an '/'.
Second bug was in inability to process security if the uri to which you deployed your app had a capital letter.
This part caused the angular app try to route to app/home/error which failed.